# How to login to FB's Graph oAuth API NOT transparently?

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

From a very old blog post from FB:

> As promised, we have changed the login procedure. This change should
>   improve your users experience and requires no modifications to
>   existing applications. **Now, if a user was already using Facebook,
>   logging into an app happens transparently.** Because of this, developers
>   might want to provide a way for users to logout by posting the word
>   "confirm" to http://www.facebook.com/logout.php. Alternatively,
>   developers can provide a link to switch the user via the login page’s
>   **"skipcookie"** parameter (as described in the authentication guide.

What if I don't want this to happen, but rather want the user to be redirected to FB and confirm his identity even if logged in to FB? I looked everywhere for this `skipcookie` directive but found nothing about it, in fact I think it has been discontinued.

For the record I'm using django in my app.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is very old, and like you said, doesn't really apply anymore especially since everything moved from oauth over to oauth 2.

> What if I don't want this to happen, but rather want the user to be redirected to FB and confirm his identity even if logged in to FB?

So here's what you do. If you want to force the user to re-login to facebook (confirming his identity and it's not some person who just walked up to an unlocked computer already logged into Facebook), call FB.logout() first, then call FB.login() to log the user in. Since you called logout() first, it will force the user to log into Facebook before authorizing your app.

Comment: Thanks DMCS, but this doesn't actually solves my problem, I knew I could just log the user out before sending him to FB but that's not very user friendly. Also I'm using django not the javascript API.

Comment: You answer below does exactly this.  It logs the user out of facebook, then you have them relogin.

Answer (score -3):

If anybody is still curious as to how to implement this using Django, here's how I log the user out of facebook server-side:

```
next_url = 'http://your.app.url/return/from/fb/'
args = {
    'next':next_url,
    'access_token':access_token
}
redirect_to = "https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?" + urllib.urlencode(args)

return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
```

With this you can log the user out using the server side script (be it python/Django or any other language/framework, just use your language's url fetching API).

With this code the user will be redirected to the FB logout url and will then return to `next_url`

Comment: But it does exactly what I suggested.  the FB.logout then FB.login.

Comment: No, I'm not using the FB javascript API, so there's no FB.logout or FB.login methods. This is how to implement it server-side.

Comment: The technique/workflow/pseudocode is what I gave you in my response and is what you used to complete the project.  I have no idea how to Django or to Python. Taking my advice then giving yourself credit for it is not nice.

Comment: You know what, I thought about this and you are right. Even though your sollution isn't exactly what I was looking for the algorythm is similar, so I switched the accepted answer. Thanks for your help @DMCS